# Get only one value from a panda condition search with loc()

Tags: pandas

Please consider 2 pandas dataframes:

balise:

[image]

And coupons

[image]

I want to replace df COUPONS['COUPON'] values by its corresponding VISIOGREEN value.

```
def ChangeIdCoupon(x):
    val = balise.loc[balise['COUPON'] == x, 'VISIOGREEN']
    if not np.isnan(val):
        return val
    else:
        return x

coupons['COUPON'] = coupons['COUPON'].apply(lambda x: ChangeIdCoupon(x))
```

In ChangeIdCoupon(x) function:

```
balise.loc[balise['COUPON'] == x, 'VISIOGREEN']
```

returns 0 or 1 value with index.

I added .iloc[0] to be sure to get only ONE value but when there are no corresponding I get
an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So how to correctly manage to get only maximum ONE value returned by:

```
balise.loc[balise['COUPON'] == x, 'VISIOGREEN']
```

Comment: Do the left join maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you are trying by using merge function, assuming that coupons are unqique in both dataframes

```
    # Merge two tables on COUPON
    coupons = pd.merge(coupons,balise,how='left',on = 'COUPON')
    # When coupon is found vison green will have value otherwise nan
    #use np.where to replace when found
    coupons['COUPON'] = np.where(coupons['VISIOGREEN'].isnull(), coupons['COUPON'], coupons['VISIOGREEN'])
```